# Advise guidance on how to form this jQuery script for show/hide fade element

Tags: jquery, fade

I basically have several links on the left side of the screen and on the right is a preview window. Below the preview window is another box for the affiliate link code.  So what I am trying to do is create an affiliate page where you choose the banner size on the left by clicking on the link and on the right you see it dynamically change to the banner size and the code changes accordingly as well.  So far I have the following code and it works but it seems very very cumbersome and bloated.  Can you see if I can trim this down?

```
jQuery(".banner-style li").click(function() {
    jQuery(".banner-style li").removeClass("selected");
    jQuery(this).addClass("selected");
    var $banner = jQuery(this).attr("class");
    $banner = $banner.replace(" selected","");
    jQuery(".preview img").fadeOut('fast',function() { 
                       jQuery(".preview img").attr("src",
                       "http://localhost/site/banners/"+$banner+".jpg")
                       .fadeIn('slow');
            });
    jQuery(".code p").removeClass('hide').hide();
    jQuery(".code p."+$banner).show();
});
```

Also to note the funny thing is in FF, when you click for the first to on any link, the original image on the right fades out and in real quick and then it loads the "clicked" image.  This does not happen in other browsers...

Answer (score 0):

you could change:

```
jQuery(this).addClass("selected");
var $banner = jQuery(this).attr("class");
$banner = $banner.replace(" selected","");
```

into:

```
var $banner = jQuery(this).attr("class");
jQuery(this).addClass("selected");
```

by changing the line sequence and removing one line `$banner` is created just after adding the "selected" class and you avoid one line.

in this set you select what is already selected:

```
jQuery(".preview img").fadeOut('fast',function() {
    jQuery(".preview img").attr("src",
    "http://localhost/site/banners/"+$banner+".jpg")
    .fadeIn('slow');
});
```

perhaps better as:

```
jQuery(".preview img").fadeOut('fast',function() {
    jQuery(this).attr("src",
    "http://localhost/site/banners/"+$banner+".jpg")
    .fadeIn('slow');
});
```

reworked:

```
jQuery(".banner-style li").click(function() {
  jQuery(".banner-style li").removeClass("selected");
  var $banner = jQuery(this).attr("class");
  jQuery(this).addClass("selected");
  jQuery(".preview img").fadeOut('fast',function() {
        jQuery(this).attr("src",
        "http://localhost/site/banners/"+$banner+".jpg")
        .fadeIn('slow');
  });
  jQuery(".code p").removeClass('hide').hide();
  jQuery(".code p."+$banner).show();
});
```

EDIT: Note about your issue with FF, would have to see the markup Css but this line seems "odd" to me:

```
jQuery(".code p").removeClass('hide').hide();
```

Comment: thanks for helping..the line you removed on the first block of code is actually needed as I need to do a string replacement to retrieve the correct class name.  As for the "odd" code you mentioned, I did that so even if javascript is disabled, it won't break anything. I added the class "hide" to all the P tags and css set to display:none.  So if JS is enabled, i remove it that class from it first but by doing that it will reveal the P so I used hide() function to hide them and show() to show the clicked element.

Comment: Since the line before the one I removed already removes that "selected" class (removeClass), by changing the order you should not have to do that string replace. I think (without testing I admit) the .removeClass('hide').hide(); is what is causing the "show and hide" behavior you see, if you change to .hide().removeClass('hide'); does that work better?